# Build and deploy a maven project via Jenkins in WAS 8

Tags: maven, jenkins, websphere-8

I have a Maven 3 project. There are two main EJB modules let say A and B and one super POM. The current build process generates a .zip files which consists of two .ear files i.e. A.ear and B.ear files. This ZIP folder is then manually deployed to Websphere. We are using was 8.0. There are multiple profiles like test, dev, local. We mention the profile name in mvn (using -P) for which we want to generate a build.

Now, our build and deployment process should be done via jenkins. The jenkins is hosted in some server. I am able to generate the build i.e. .zip file successfully in the jenkins default workspace. However, i dont know the next step of deploying it to the websphere server. I am completely new to websphere as well as to the project. Please let me know what steps needs to be followed to deploy it in was 8.0. Do i need to write any build scripts? If any further setting information is required in order to answer this question then let me know i will find out and will post it.

Comment: This is too broad question. I'd recommend you to start with the following, although it talks about WebSphere Liberty it will give you some starting points: DevOps with Liberty, Maven, and Chef - https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/devops-liberty-maven-chef-part-1/ and Configuring and Deploying Open Source with WebSphere Application Server - http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248194.html?Open

Comment: thanks. I will try with Liberty

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old thread, but I have spent alot of time trying to figure out the same problem so here I am providing the solution which worked for me and might help someone in need.

Install WebSphere Deployer Plugin

- Go to : Manage Jenkins -> Go to Plugin Manager -> Available ->
  Websphere Deployer -> Install it.
  [image]
- The WebSphere Deployer Plugin needs additional libraries. For WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5 (used in this example) this libraries are the

> `com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar`
>
> `com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar`

- Both files are located in:

> ```
> <WebSphere-Installation>/runtimes/
> ```

Copy the JARs to

> ```
> <Jenkins-Installation-Path>/plugins/websphere-deployer/WEB-INF/lib
> ```

- Restart Jenkins.
- Invoke Post-build Actions -> Select Deploy to IBM Websphere
  Application Server
  [image]
- Go to WebSphere Deployment -> Input details as per below:

> `EAR/WAR Path: jobDescription/**/folder1/**/folder2/*.ear`
>
> `Deployment Targets: WebSphere:cell=[ReplaceWithCellName],node=[ReplaceWithNodeName],server=[ReplaceWithServer]`

- Save the config and Proceed to build

***NOTE: Other things in WAS config you might need to set as per your requirement.***

Comment: Also note, some EJB deployments require additional jar files in <WebSphere-Installation>/runtimes/. It just depends on the application. And as always, if you copy a new jar dependency in the websphere-deployer lib folder, you must restart jenkins for the plugin to see it.